# How do I remove Vue from being loaded when using elixir?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 and elixir to compile my Sass and JS.

My `/resources/assets/js/app.js` file contains only 2 lines:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./search');
```

`search.js` contains some custom JS, nothing to do with Vue.

However, when I open the JS console I can see that Vue is being loaded (I see the Vue devtools extension prompts and "You are running Vue in development mode.")

How can I remove Vue from my project entriely?

My gulpfile.js is pasted below:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.publicPath = 'public_html/assets';

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

Comment: Why you remove vue ?, on serious note:  `rm -rf node_modules` and again do `npm install`, `grep vue` in code.

Comment: Since Laravel 5.3 vue is included by default. You could rollback to Laravel 5.2 or remove it manually from the source.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.5 there is the command

```
php artisan preset none
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Vue Dependency by deleting the VueJs entries in your `package.json` and run `npm update`. To be sure, you can remove the node_modules dir and run `npm install`